# Convolution of decaying polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I conjecture that if the functions $f$, $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying
$$|f(x)| ≤ A(1+|x|)^{−M}, \quad |g(x)| ≤ B(1+|x|)^{−N}$$for some
$M$, $N > n$, then$$|(f * g)(x)| ≤ ABC(1+|x|)^{−L},$$where $L = \min(N,M)$ and $C =C(N,M) > 0$.

From playing around, I've had the idea that the inequality$$(1+|x-y|)^{-k}\le (1+|y|)^k(1+|x|)^{-k}$$might be used to estimate the decay of this convolution.

I currently have$$|(f *g)(x)| ≤ AB\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|x-y|)^{−M}(1+|y|)^{−N}dy \le AB(1+|x|)^{-M}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|y|)^{M−N}dy.$$

But there is a problem, as$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(1+|y|)^{M−N}dy$$is not integrable if $M-N \ge -n$.

How do we fix the problem?

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question for MSE, but too elementary for this site. (Hint: Consider separately the contributions from $|y-x|\le |x|/2$ and $|y-x|>|x|/2$ for a large $|x|$.)